# how can i create plist like below in image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

Iam trying to create a plist with following feature.

Inside plist there are two keys
1.id
2.status

current values are  id:91  status:buy    here Id should be unique .Means   if i tried to add a 3rd entry like    id:91 status:downlaod .Then it should replace the existing  91  and status:buy with new one.

please help  me 
check below image  [image]

How can i remove the status and id  if i got one match in Id?

Comment: From where new entry is going to be add? Please provide that code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate root array and compare id value in dictionary

```
NSMutableArray *rootArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"91",@"id",@"Buy",@"status",nil];
NSDictionary *dic1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"92",@"id",@"Download",@"status",nil];
[rootArray addObject:dic];
[rootArray addObject:dic1];
```

[image]

```
NSDictionary *dic3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"91",@"id",@"Download",@"status",nil];
NSDictionary *foundMatch =nil;

for(NSDictionary *dictionary in rootArray)
{
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[dic3 objectForKey:@"id"]]) {
        foundMatch = dictionary;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundMatch!=nil) {
    [rootArray removeObject:foundMatch];
    [rootArray addObject:dic3];
}
else {
    [rootArray addObject:dic3];
}
[rootArray writeToFile:@"path" atomically:YES];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is `.plist` file which has array of dictionary and each dictionary has two key

> id
>   status

I give you [official documentation for How to create plist file programmatically.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html)